# "Potential" pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I was raised to pronounce "potential" with a long o (ō). This makes sense where the syllables are divided. Yet, the online dictionaries I have checked say it is "puh". Can you comment?

Comment: Well, I'm British, and I definitely wouldn't give it a long o. However it is noticeable that Americans tend to use the long o for all sorts of things where we hardly pronounce the o at all. Most embarrassing of all was when President Reagan, at the time of the ending of the Berlin Wall, kept referring to Poo-land. I don't suppose the Poles noticed, but it sounded a bit silly to the British.

Comment: What's the question? "*Can you comment?*" Yes. My comment is that there is no question here, or it is too broad - it should be closed.

Comment: @Drew It sounds a fair question to me - how do you pronounce *potential*?

Comment: @WS2: So is it a poll of those who answer?

Comment: Maybe Kelly should investigate "schwa" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa

Comment: In upstate New York we say "puh".

Comment: I hear both "PO" and "puh", sometimes from the same speaker.

Comment: @WS2 As bad as when JFK called himself a pastry?

Answer (score 2):

It would be too prescriptive to say it is pronounced one way or the other. I looked into some dictionary IPA spellings and they have the shwa for that 'uh' sound. Vowels are tricky things though. It might be shwa in the dictionary, but that's not a strict guideline. You might not notice it, but even you might say is as p'uh'tential if you are talking really fast...vice versa for other users (I tend to say p-oh-tential if I'm saying it slow).

Just don't pronounce it as 'carrot' and you won't raise any eyebrows.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal in the majority dialect to make the first syllable of "potential" unstressed, since the second syllable is stressed, and the first syllable has a lax vowel and is open.  And generally, unstressed non-high vowels reduce to schwa.  All the same, I often hear tense and unreduced "o" and "e" in such initial syllables in American English.  Apparently, the vowels are tensed for clarity. The words where tense and unreduced "e" (i.e., [i:]) seems to be an option are words like "eliminate", "electricity", "deliver".

Comment: Why do you say the first syllable has a lax vowel? Like the OP, I would pronounce it as tense /o:/ or /ou/ if I didn't reduce the vowel.

Comment: @sumelic, if it were phonologically tense, in the **SPE** treatment, it would be stressed, and could not be reduced.  Evidently, it can be phonetically tense (which is what I said).